# Replace urls with the shortened version - Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, url-shortener

Replacing the urls in a block of plain text is done by looking for url regular expressions. I am using string.gsub(regex, "\1") to achieve the same.

I would like to know how to proceed if the shortened url (using api's of any url shortening service) is to be used as the replacement and not the original url.

I am using Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gsub(regex) {|url| shorten_url(url)}
```

Where shorten_url is a method that takes a url and returns a shorter url as a string suppled by a url shortening service.

Comment: perfect! Never knew that gsub accepts a block. I should rtm more :) Thanks!